# How to get axes labels with MultiaxisArrangement

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am delighted to see the new MultiaxisArrangement feature, but when I tried it, I could not figure out how to label the two axes. For example, the following produces no axis labels. Nor does any configuration of AxesLabel or FrameLabel that I have tried.

```
ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3}, 10 {3, 2, 1}}
, MultiaxisArrangement -> All
, FrameLabel -> {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The `InputForm` of that plot does not look right. Seems like a bug to me. You should report it to Wolfram Support.

Comment: yet another bug when  `MultiaxisArrangement`  is used: `PlotLegends` is ignored.

Answer (score 12):

For a workaround use [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Labeled[
 ListLinePlot[
  {{1, 2, 3}, 10 {3, 2, 1}},
  MultiaxisArrangement -> All],
 {"bottom", Rotate["left", Pi/2],
  "top", Rotate["right", Pi/2]}, All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Or more simply,

```
Labeled[
 ListLinePlot[
  {{1, 2, 3}, 10 {3, 2, 1}},
  MultiaxisArrangement -> All],
 {"bottom", "left", "top", "right"}, All,
 RotateLabel -> True]
```

(* same picture *)

Answer (score 9):

A work-around that works with arbitrary number of axes: post-process to inject the option [`AxisLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisLabel.html) to [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html)s:

```
ClearAll[fixMultiAxisLabels]
fixMultiAxisLabels[off_ : 1.5, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{al = #2}, 
    ReplaceAll[Offset[o : Except[0, _], z_] :> Offset[off  o, z]]@*
      ReplaceAll[AxisObject[a_, b_, c___] :> 
        AxisObject[a, b, Last[al = RotateLeft[al]], opts, c]]@#] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
llp = ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3}, 10 {3, 2, 1}}, 
    MultiaxisArrangement -> All, ImageSize -> 500];

labels = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

axislabels = Thread[AxisLabel -> Placed @@@
Transpose[{labels, {0.5, {0.5, #}}&/@ {-2.5, 2.5, 2.5, -.5}}]]

fixMultiAxisLabels[][llp, axislabels]
```

[image]

```
llp2 = ListLinePlot[{10000 {1, 2, 3}, 10 10000 {3, 2, 1}}, 
     MultiaxisArrangement -> All, ImageSize -> 500, LabelStyle -> 16];

axislabels2 = Thread[AxisLabel -> Placed @@@ 
    Transpose[{labels, {0.5, {0.5, #}} & /@ {-3.5, 5, 2.5, -.5}}]]

fixMultiAxisLabels[][llp2, axislabels2]
```

[image]

An example with 4 vertical axes:

```
llp3 = ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3}, 10 {3, 2, 1}, 500 {2, 1, 3}, 1000 {1, 3, 2}}, 
   MultiaxisArrangement -> All, ImageSize -> 800];

labels3 = {"left 1", "left 2", "right 1", "right 2", "bottom", "top"};

axislabels3 = Thread[AxisLabel -> Placed @@@ 
   Transpose[{labels3, {0.5, {0.5, #}} & /@ {-2, -1.25, 3.25, 4,  2.5, -.5} }]];

fixMultiAxisLabels[2, LabelStyle -> 14][llp3, axislabels3]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but MultiaxisArrangement seems half hearted to me. It doesn't work for DateListPlot and leaving out axis labels is pretty fundamental. Even the use of colour for the axis identification is OK for Mathematica users but not for distribution of the result to others.

Answer (score 6):

Another work-around: Add the frame labels using `Show`.

`addFrameLabels` adds desired frame labels using an invisible frame and ticks to adjust the positioning of labels:

```
ClearAll[addFrameLabels]
addFrameLabels[gap_ : .01] := Show[#, FrameLabel -> #2, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{#, #} & @ {{.5, Invisible["m"], {0, gap}}}, 
         {{{.5, Invisible["m"], {0, gap/10}}}, None}}, 
    FrameStyle -> StrokeForm[Opacity[0]],  PlotRangePadding -> 0] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
addFrameLabels[][ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3}, 10 {3, 2, 1}}, 
    MultiaxisArrangement -> All, ImageSize -> 500], 
  {{"A", "B"}, { "C", "D"}}]
```

[image]

```
addFrameLabels[.07][ListLinePlot[{10000 {1, 2, 3}, 10 10000 {3, 2, 1}}, 
      MultiaxisArrangement -> All, ImageSize -> 500], 
  {{"A", "B"}, { "C", "D"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: this works only for two multi-axes.