# 1 plot two different y scales

Tags: plotting

I looked several similar questions but still have problems to write down the code by myself. I have two plots with the same x axis, is there a simple way to put them together but with different y scales? also how can I added two different y axis names?

`Data1={{0., 0.}, {3.5, 2.6}, {7., 5.5}, {10.5, 6.2}, {14., 6.6}, {17.5,  7.8}}; Data2={{3.5, 2134.}, {7., 2250.}, {10.5, 2435.}, {14., 17.2}, {17.5, 16.8}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the new-in-version-13.0 option [`MultiaxisArrangement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiaxisArrangement.html)

```
llp = ListLinePlot[{Data1, Data2},  
    MultiaxisArrangement -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, due to a bug the option `FrameLabel` does not work as expected ([see this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261425/125)). As a work-around we can use the function `addFrameLabels` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261439/125) to add frame labels:

```
addFrameLabels[][llp, 
    {{Style["data 1", 16], Style["data 2", 16]} , {Style["x", 16], None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, what if I only want to show the points? I just need to change the "ListLinePlot" to "ListPlot"?

Comment: right. Or just add the option `Joined -> False` in `ListLinePlot`.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach:

1. Rescale the second column of `Data2` so that it has the same range
   as the second column of `Data1`.
2. Change the tick labels of the right frame using  the function `` Charting`FindTicks ``

```
{yminmax1, yminmax2} = MinMax /@ {Data1[[All, 2]], Data2[[All, 2]]};

data2Rescaled = Transpose[{#, Rescale[#2, yminmax2, yminmax1]}] & @@ Transpose[Data2];

ListLinePlot[{Data1, data2Rescaled}, 
 Mesh -> All,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> {Directive[LineColor -> ColorData[97]@#] & /@ {1, 2}, 
    {Automatic, Automatic}},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[yminmax1, yminmax2]}, 
    {Automatic, All}},
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["data 1", 14], Style["data 2", 14]}, {Style["x", 14], None}}]
```

[image]

Use `ListPlot` instead of `ListLinePlot` to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!