# How Can You Label Axes in a MultiAxis Plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

With standard plots axis labelling works like this:

```
    ListLinePlot[{Range[10], RandomInteger[50, 10]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Var1", "Var2"}]
```

[image]

But suppose you want to do a similar plot as a multi-axis plot:

```
ListLinePlot[{Range[10], RandomInteger[50, 10]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Var1", "Var2"}, MultiaxisArrangement -> All]
```

This gives you a multiaxis plot, but without any labels:

[image]

What's the correct method to label each Y-Axis?

Comment: I think it's a deficiency approaching a bug that neither `AxesLabel` can be used nor `FrameLabel` works with `MultiaxisArrangement`.

Comment: related / possible duplicate: [How to get axes labels with MultiaxisArrangement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261425/125)